# Can I have my device (alarm clock) play audio files on Google home speakers

Tags: api, sdk, chromecast, google-assistant-sdk

I have made an alarm clock (using microcontrollers) that plays audio files at different times of the day. Can I make my device play audio files on Google home speakers in the house under same wifi? I will need it to play audio by itself with no input from the user (like pushing cast button)

Please help!
Ishtiaque

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature isn't currently supported. Third party actions for the Google Assistant require immediate [invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit), so audio playback can't be scheduled ahead of time.

Comment: I have been trying to find a way to bypass this issues. If I have Google Assistant SDK on my microcontroller alarm clock, do you think it is possible to add the alarm clock on Google Home app and then it can play the audio alarm on all devices?